# How do I get the index to take the filename as its value?

Tags: loops, indexing, filenames

I have a list of filenames that I want to make (they don't exist yet). I want to loop through the list and create each file. Next I want to write to each file a path (along with other text not shown here) that includes the name of the file. I have written something similar to below so far but cannot see how to get the index i to take the file name values. Please help.

import os
biglist=['sleep','heard','shed']

for i in biglist:

```
myfile=open('C:\autumn\winter\spring\i.txt','w')
myfile.write('DATA =  c:\autumn\winter\spring\i.dat')
myfile.close
```

Comment: Please show what one of the files contains, after you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this below python function.

```
import sys
biglist=['sleep','heard','shed']
def create_file():
     for i in biglist:
       try:
         file_name_with_ext = "C:\autumn\winter\spring\"+ i + ".txt" 
         file = open(file_name_with_ext, 'a')
         file.close()
       except:
           print("caught error!")
           sys.exit(0) 

create_file() #invoking the function
```